# JS hide button when change select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

I have simple form:

```
<form action="">
    <select name="gender" onchange="myFunction()">
        <option value="m">male</option>
        <option value="f">female</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="1">
    <input type="submit" id="save1" value="Save">
</form>

<form action="">
    <select name="gender" onchange="myFunction()">
        <option value="m">male</option>
        <option value="f">female</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="2">
    <input type="submit" id="save2" value="Save">
</form>
```

JS:

```
function myFunction() {
    $("#save").first().hide();
}
```

I want to hide button "Save" only if select ('gender') have changed option for each user (form).

Problem is, that when I change gender for user 2, then button for user 1 hide.

*Note: there are many forms and users*

Comment: invalid markup..`id's` cant be duplicate.

Comment: give different id to both buttons, it will work

Comment: @Kartikeya Good point. Changed. I was creating forms by function.

Comment: provide a fiddle and so that we will look in the matter closely..

Comment: "I want to hide button "Save" only if select ('gender') have changed option for each user (form)." Do you want to hide all the buttons when all the select options are changed or do you want the button of only that select should be hidden which changes ?

Comment: @TusharRaj second option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("select").change(function() {
  $(this).parent("form").find("input[type='submit']").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("select").on("change", function() {
    $(this).parent().children('input[type=submit]').hide();
});
```

Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AmanVirdi/pvbaLfxf/)

Answer (score 0):

Or like this:

```
$('form>select').change(function(e){
    $(e.currentTarget).siblings("input[type='submit']").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use jquery, bind action on form and trigger on 'select' box, then use siblings to find the button inside that form.
Example :

```
$('form').on('change', 'select', function() {
    var condition = ($(this).val() && $(this).val() != ""); // true : show button, false : hide button
         $(this).siblings('input[type="submit"]').toggle(condition);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :- [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zhpatafb/1/)

```
$("select").on("change",function () {
$(this).parent().find("input[type=submit]").hide();
});
```